# Getting second last occurrence and capturing the string after that

Tags: javascript

I have the following url string as a example

```
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/101/'
```

I want to store `101` so I can use that part of string in some other logic. I tried the following.

```
const filter = (value)=>{
    return value.split("/").pop();
})
```

but it returns empty, from what I know, as pop(), pop off last but and last bit is only / and nothing after that.

How can I modify my code to give me the value after the second to last /

Comment: The API returns JSON, not a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split, the last / gets split as an empty string, which you receive when you pop(). If we remove it before splitting you will get the result you want.

You could do this oneliner
    `value.slice(0, -1).split('/').pop();`

Comment: Thanks, but can u expand on ur answer as I am not that familiar with logically breaking down things in one line of code.

Comment: @Nofel `slice` removes part of a string. In this case it removes the last character. So the trailing `/` in the end of the string will be removed. After that `pop()` does its job as you expect because the second last `/` becomes the last one instead. It works, but obviously will cause issues if there's no trailing `/` in the end of the URL input.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not sure if there will be a trailing slash, you can use filter to remove all empty elements, and then pop the '101':

```js
const filter = value => value.split('/').filter(i => i).pop()

console.log(filter('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/101/'))
console.log(filter('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/101'))
```

`filter(i => i)` simply loops over each item in the array to see if it evaluates to true, so all falsy items like '' or undefined will be removed.

Comment: that is compact, never used ```filter``` before

Comment: This is the only answer that considers both trailing `/` or not. Hence the best answer in my honest opinion. Well done.

Comment: @icecub Thanks, I've had this issue many times and my goto is to filter on whenever splitting the url :P

Answer (score 1):

Because the URL ends in the delimiter you're splitting on, the last item in the resulting array will be the empty string, and the second-to-last item will be the match you're looking for. You can `.pop()` twice:

```
const filter = (value)=>{
  const splits = value.split('/');
  splits.pop();
  return splits.pop();
};
```

Or you could use a regular expression to match non-`/` characters, followed by `/` and the end of the string::

```js
const filter = value => value.match(/[^\/]+(?=\/$)/)[0];
console.log(filter('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/101/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the number before the last '/' as follows.

```
const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/101/';

const filter = value => {
    let segments = value.split('/');
    return segments[ segments.length -2];
}

console.log(filter(url));
```